# Wow.js offset equal to element height

Tags: javascript, jquery-animate, wow.js

According to the wow.js documentation I can set the bottom offset at which the animation will trigger:

```
  wow = new WOW(
    {
      boxClass:     'wow',      // default
      animateClass: 'animated', // default
      offset:       0,          // < --------------- This one
      mobile:       true,       // default
      live:         true        // default
    }
  )
  wow.init();
```

I have a .foo container `<div class="foo wow fadeIn"></div>` I want to animate when its bottom hits the bottom of the viewport i.e. it is fully on my screen. So I guess the offset should be equal to the .foo element height. Is there any way to specify this in the wow.js settings above?

Answer (score 6):

Since the bottom offset can be defined with a `data-wow-offset` attrubute I came up with this solution:

```
$(".wow").each(function() {
  var wowHeight = $(this).height();
  $(this).attr("data-wow-offset", wowHeight);
});
```

Hope this will help somebody. Also I'd be glad to know of a more elegant solution.